# Same query but different result when ran in different database servers

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a local environment running MariaDB server version 10.2.14 and a production environment running MariaDB server version 10.1.40.

When running a calculation based on the haversine formula to calculate distance between 2 geolocations, my local environment returns 0 as the result, but the prod environment returns null.

A sample query is below:

```
select (acos(cos(radians((41.480473))) * cos(radians(41.480473)) *
 cos(radians((-81.630990)) - radians(-81.630990)) + 
 sin(radians((41.480473))) * sin(radians(41.480473))) * 3958.755
 ) as distance
```

The result should be zero because it is essentially trying to get the distance between 2 locations with the same geolocation info.

Can anyone shed some light why my prod environment is giving me a null value when running the above sample instead of zero?

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from rounding errors for the outmost `acos`-function. The other system may give you exactly 1 while the other system may give you bit over 1 due to rounding errors. Valid parameters for `acos` are from 1 is 0 and `acos` value > 1 is NULL.

You can use `ROUND` before the outmost `acos` and make the calculation a function for easier use:

```
create function f_distance_in_miles( 
in_lat1 decimal(9,7),
in_long1 decimal(9,7),
in_lat2 decimal(9,7),
in_long2 decimal(9,7)
)
returns float
deterministic
begin

declare v_i real;

set v_i = cos(radians(in_lat1)) *  cos(radians(in_lat2)) *  cos(radians(in_long1) 
   - radians(in_long2))
   + sin(radians(in_lat1)) * sin(radians(in_lat2));

if (v_i<-1) then
  set v_i = -1;
elseif (v_i>1) then
  set v_i = 1;
end if;

return acos(v_i)*3958.755;

end
```

And then use it like:

```
select f_distance_in_miles(41.480473, -81.630990, 41.480473, -81.630990)
```

Comment: No.  `ROUNDing` the intermediate result will simply change which values cause the problem.

Comment: @RickJames The rounding error happens on last digits after the decimal point (1.0000000000000002). Rounding that to 7 digits would have eliminated the problem with any values (you can always prove me wrong). The real problem was that some precision was lost due to rounding (0.5 miles), but then again, the formula is not that precise either. For best results, it's better just to check if the intermediate result was out of bounds and fix that. Improved the answer.

Comment: Slightly shorter:  `if (abs(v_i) > 1 then set v_i = round(v_i); end if;`  Even better:  `if (abs(v_i) > 1) then return 0; end if;`  When can -1 occur?

Comment: I rejected Haversine 4 years ago:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#postlog